# Stripe API - Passing a custom parameter does not work for subscription charges

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm creating a new checkout session and creating a new subscription on that page.

```
return stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    customer_email=payload['email'],
    line_items=_get_checkout_products(payload),
    mode='subscription',
    success_url=host + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&success=true',
    cancel_url=host + '?canceled=true',
    subscription_data={
        "metadata": {
            'user_id': get_account_id(event)
        }
    }
)
```

Unfortunately it only shows on subscription.created event but not in charges for said subscription for the next period.
Why is it not showing up in the next invoice.payment_succeeded or charge.succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for this - currently there's no way to pass parameters reliably between all events.